# Prisma how can I update only some of the models fields in update()

Tags: express, prisma

I have a Prisma model with lets say 10 fields.
Think User model with firstname, lastname, address, e-mail , phone, mobile, age etc.

I am trying to write a update method for this, where I most of the times only want to update some or only 1 of the fields. Not the whole User. If the field is not sent with the request, I want to keep the value from the db.

What would the best practice be for this. Should I check for all fields to be in the req object?
How could I write this for prisma?

Example on how I would like it to work:

```
req = {firstname: 'Bob', email: 'bob@bob.bob', etc}

const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    email: 'viola@prisma.io',
  },
  data: {
    req.firstname ? (email: req.firstname) : null,
    req.email ? (email: req.email) : null,
    req.address? (email: req.address) : null,
  },
})
```

Or should I check for values to be present in req and build the data object in 10 versions:

```
let customDataObject = {}
if (req.firstname) {
   customDataObject.firstname = req.firstname
}
if (req.email) {
   customDataObject.email= req.email
}

const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    email: 'viola@prisma.io',
  },
  data: customDataObject,
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `undefined` property is used in Prisma to do exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Basically, when a field is assigned `undefined` it means **ignore this and do nothing for this field**.

You can learn more about this in the article about [`null` and `undefined`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/null-and-undefined#use-case-null-and-undefined-in-a-graphql-resolver) in the docs.

This is what your update query should look like:

```js
// Assuming email, firstname and address fields exist in your prisma schema. 
const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
  where: {
    email: 'viola@prisma.io',
  },
  data: {
    // If req.firstname is falsy, then return undefined, otherwise return it's value
    firstname: req.firstname || undefined,
    email: req.email || undefined, 
    address: req.address || undefined
  },
})
```